# user.identity.isauthenticated return false always in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, authentication

In MVC application I am using `user.identity.isauthenticated` to check for authenticated users. However in `IE 11` always return this as `false`. While Chrome and Firefox it acts correctly.

Any Idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source SO

suspect that this problem is related to how ASP .NET v4 handles cookies with IE11. Have you tried setting cookieless="UseCookies" attribute in forms element in your web.config?

Read here for more information:

http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/aspnet-40-forms-authentication-issues-with-ie11/

How did harmless crawler bypass WebForms authentication, and hijack a user's session?

Found the solution based on this question "Internet Explorer 11 does not authenticates on some of the sites"
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11_pr-windows8_1_pr/internet-explorer-11-does-not-authenticates-on/47382440-71e5-4a66-ab41-1c070abbd3e5

While the exact solution did not work for me, it got me in the right direction. That is to look at .NET on the server. It seems that there are a couple of .NET updates that are keeping up with IE11.

solution was to install .NET 4.5 on the server
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: Yes I did that, and it got resolved too. Thanks for answering.